# Taxonomy view links do not link to page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've created a view that displays the node count values for taxonomy terms. After implementing it into my Drupal site, I found that I cannot access the taxonomy term page from the links provided, all it does is redirect me to the home page.

My settings are as follows:

[image]

It produces the following view, and I click the links I cannot access the taxonomy term page:

[image]

I've tested the links manually and they work, they are:

```
/?q=tags/expansion
/?q=tags/opportunity
/?q=tags/press
/?q=tags/product-update
```

Any reasons why this isn't working as expected? I'd greatly appreciate your help.

**UPDATE #1 - rendered output**

```
<ul class="views-summary">
      <li><a href="/home/">expansion</a>
              (2)
          </li>
      <li><a href="/home/">opportunity</a>
              (4)
          </li>
      <li><a href="/home/">press</a>
              (1)
          </li>
      <li><a href="/home/">product update</a>
              (1)
          </li>
    </ul>
```

**UPDATE 2 - Configure field: Taxonomy term: Name**

[image]

**UPDATE 3 - Configure contextual filter: Taxonomy term: Name**

[image]

Comment: Please paste the rendered output (html source) of one of the links and its parent element.

Comment: @murraybiscuit - I've made the update

Comment: It seems strange that views is generating clean urls but you're using query strings. In the field: taxonomy term name can you post a screenshot? I'm assuming you've selected the box linking the term to its term page. Maybe you've enabled URL rewriting and just left a slash in there. Can you post a screenshot of your field setting.

Comment: @murraybiscuit - I've included the screenshots

Comment: The issue seems to be the base path in your contextual filter. It's not set, so it's defaulting to home. You could try adding "tags" as your base path, which may work depending on how you've got Pathauto set up (I'd highly recommend using Pathauto if you aren't already). I can't say that I remember doing a tag count list this way (with a contextual filter). I seem to remember having to use a plugin or aggregating on relationships before.